# Incrementing a Constant in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, undefined-behavior

Can someone explain to me as why this code works? I feel like the compiler should not allow me to do what I have done (move an int pointer to point at a const int), or alternatively I would at least expect a compiler warning or a segfault. The idea of changing the value of a constant just seems so wrong.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct test_struct {
    int i;
    const int j;
};

int main() {
    cout << "Create a struct with int i = 100 and const int j = 101." << endl;
    test_struct test{100, 101};
    cout << test.i << endl;
    cout << test.j << endl;
    cout << "Create pointer p and point it to int i." << endl;
    int* p1 = &test.i;
    cout << *p1 << endl;
    cout << "Increment pointer p, which should now be pointing at const int j." << endl;
    p1++;
    cout << *p1 << endl;
    cout << "Dereference p and increment it." << endl;
    (*p1)++;
    cout << *p1 << endl;
    cout << test.j << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Create a struct with int i = 100 and const int j = 101.
100
101
Create pointer p and point it to int i.
100
Increment pointer p, which should now be pointing at const int j.
101
Dereference p and increment it.
102
102
```

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using the g++ compiler.

Comment: A better title would be: Modifying a constant in a struct by incrementing a pointer to a non-const member.

Comment: C++ gives you great power, but with it comes great responsibility. You can get yourself into real trouble if you do things that don't make sense.

Comment: **Do not get used to doing this.** const members are not meant to be changed; that is the purpose of the `const` keyword. Even if this is allowed to compile, it could be incredibly dangerous when working with someone else's structs. Or yours, for that matter.

Comment: @rolledback _"Incrementing a Constant in C++"_ Sorry, the title sounds so wrong already!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You program invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in two ways, which means the behavior of your program is unpredictable, even seemingly normal behavior is possible.

First although we can treat the individual elements of a struct as arrays once you increment the pointer it is no longer valid to dereference it, it does not not even have to be pointing to the next element it could very well be pointing to padding.

Second, attempting to alter a const in also undefined behavior. The [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `7.1.6.1` *The cv-qualifiers* paragraph *4* which says:

> [...]any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

We can see for the purposes of pointer arithmetic a non-array variable is treated as an array of one element, from section `5.7` *Additive operators* which says:

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object
>   behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of
>   length one with the type of the object as its element type.

and furthermore dereferecing one past the end of an array is undefined behavior, from the same section:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. [...]
>   If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object,
>   the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior
>   is undefined.

we can further see from section `5.3.1` *Unary operators* which says:

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it
>   is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an **lvalue referring to the object** or
>   function

when we dereference a pointer we expect and *object* which we are not guaranteed to have once we are one past the end.

The [The GNU C++ Library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/iterators.html) has an easier to access explanation which says (*emphasis mine*):

> You can only dereference a pointer that points into an array. If your
>   array pointer points outside the array -- even to just one past the
>   end -- and you dereference it, **Bad Things happen.**

Comment: Which draft? It'd be better to add the draft version for future reference.

Comment: Alright. That does make sense since my professor said something quite similar. I guess I'm more surprised that in this case, the undefined behavior isn't something like a segfault or p pointing to some weird spot in memory.

Comment: @Csq added link to the draft I was referencing.

Comment: @rolledback the link to the undefined behavior Wikipedia entry should be helpful. Undefined behavior means the result is unpredictable which includes crashing or what seems like normal behavior.

Comment: "you can not treat a struct like an array and increment a pointer to the next element " - actually that is legal if the pointer is not dereferenced, as the rest of your post explains!

Comment: also, arguably in C++ it is legal to dereference that pointer to read `j` if we have checked that there is no padding between `i` and `j`. There doesn't seem to be any text in the standard which says that a one-past-the-end pointer is not dereferencable.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: There's text somewhere that you can't read/write to it, which makes dereferencing pointless though not explicitly illegal.

Comment: @rolledback very happy to help you may also find [Deep C](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) very interesting and of course reading questions in the [undefined behavior tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior?sort=newest&pageSize=50) can be very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer is correct for Visual Studio 2010 - not sure about other compilers.)*

Here is the reason why this is allowed:

The `const` modifier is an instruction to the compiler to prevent the user from editing that declared variable. When working with that variable the compiler will prevent you from making changes to it, and require you to add the `const` modifier to pointers associated with that particular variable.

However, all like other variable values, it resides in memory, and the compiler doesn't specifically prevent access to or editing of that memory. It can be accessed and modified just like any other memory address using a pointer, if you choose to subvert the compiler's instructions, as you have done in your code.

If you are looking to prevent program access to areas in memory, you can refer to the following memory protection constants for Windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: _"So here is the reasoning as to why you can do this."_ Doesn't UB stay UB?

Comment: I should point out that just because you can do this doesn't mean you should or that it is good coding practice. He did ask for a explanation of why it worked.

Comment: Considering such as a valid _"coding practice"_ by the most remote possibility, is obviously wrong (not to say ridiculous).

Comment: for the most part UB stays UB. Although with structures there are ways to pack your values to prevent UB when using pointers. See: <http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/>

Comment: +1 : I think this is an accurate and concise answer, at least with respect to VS.

Answer (score -1):

the data items in the structure are stored on stack in memory,so when you create a pointer and make it point to the first item,the address that is stored is the position of the stack pointer.when u increment it the stack pointer increments to the next location on stack i.e the second data item.
thus this might be the possible reason.because otherwise it should have given an error,and also we can't treat a structure like an array. Bt still its able to point to the next item,possible only if we consider the stack created in memory.